# How to get the positive score only?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, sentiment-analysis, vader

I am new to sentiment analysis.I want to get the positive score only not all like compound,neg ,pos,neutral.Can anyone help me to achieve this?

```
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
ss = sid.polarity_scores(sentence)
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [source code](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/sentiment/vader.html), the method returns a *dictionary* with shape:

```
{"neg" : ..., "neu" : ..., "pos" : ..., "compound" : ...}
```

So you can simply use:

```
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
ss = sid.polarity_scores(sentence)['pos'] # the positive score
```

Here `['pos']` fetches the value that is associated with the `'pos'` key.